# Is it possible to change the Response Code when user authorization fails in a datasnap server?

Tags: delphi, datasnap

Is it possible to change the HTTP Response Code in my DataSnap (Delphi XE3) server when user authorization fails? Currently it's returning *HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error*, which can happen in many other scenarios, and doesn't help describe the problem.

Along the same idea, is it possible to change the default Response Body? Currently, it's returning *{"error":"USER is not authorized to perform the requested action."}*, which is fine, but I'd like to return a custom JSON object if possible.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up executing code that looked like this in TDSAuthenticationManager.OnUserAuthorize

```
  if valid = false then
  begin
    GetInvocationMetadata.ResponseCode := 403;
    GetInvocationMetadata.ResponseMessage := JSONResponseObject.ToString;
    GetInvocationMetadata.ResponseContent := JSONResponseOjbect.ToString;
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to get the THTTPDSResponse inside a serverclass? Ex:

```
TServerClass1.EchoString(val: string);
begin
  GetDSResponse.Header.Add('someheader');
end;
```