# How to raise validation errors (HTTP status code 400) in Delphi DataSnap REST

Tags: delphi, datasnap

By default - if DataSnap method (which is declared inside `{$METHODINFO ON}` and `{$METHODINFO OFF}`) experiences exception, then DataSnap returns HTTP response with status code 500 and simple message `{"error":"SQL error... whatever..."}`. That is fine for system errors, but I would like to handle validation errors separately - by returning extended error message and HTTP code 400. Is it possible to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674634/is-it-possible-to-change-the-response-code-when-user-authorization-fails-in-a-da apparently gives answer